# Restrict SSH-login with public-key only to selected users

Tags: permissions, ssh, remote, openssh, remote-login

Using `OpenSSH`, I have enabled ssh-login to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, call it `Remote` and my user account on `Remote` is called `Remote-User`. I have also made sure that login is only possible by means of public-key authentication. Here comes the actual description of the problem.

I have two local machines, call them `Local-A` and `Local-B`, and each of them has one user, call them `User-A` and `User-B`, respectively. I would like to restrict access to `Remote-User@Remote` to only `User-A` and `User-B` and disallow other users, irrespective of whether their public key has been added to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of `Remote-User@Remote`. I tried doing so by adding the line

`AllowUsers User-A User-B`

to `sshd_config` but I noticed that `User-B` had ssh access to `Remote-User@Remote` even if I simply had

`AllowUsers User-A`

This makes me think that any user whose public-key has been added to `Remote-User@Remote`'s `.ssh/authorized_keys` file will have access, irrespective of any restrictions I try to impose using `AllowUsers`.

I was wondering if anybody has any suggestions on how to tackle this. Bear in mind that I not well-versed in this domain so I might have omitted important information. If so, please let me know and I am happy to update this question.

Comment: Sounds confusing.  User keys are intended to be specific to the user.  I have different keys for different machines.  Saying that a key should be enabled, but not from a specific machine - how will you ensure that "specific machine" is the one it claims to be?  That's the points of the SSH Keys - identify a user uniquely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AllowUsers` option in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file is exactly what you need to accomplish user access restriction via `ssh`.

See the manpage for [sshd_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

```
AllowUsers
      This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.
      If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.
      Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.  By default, login
      is allowed for all users.  If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and
      HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular
      hosts.  HOST criteria may additionally contain addresses to match in CIDR
      address/masklen format.  The allow/deny users directives are processed in the
      following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers.
```

In order for the changes in `sshd_config` to take effect, you need to restart the `sshd` service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

If that still does not work, check the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` folder for any additional configuration files, that overrule your `AllowUsers` statement.

Comment: I think I always forgot to restart the service. I can't really test this idea right now because I can't physically access the server (due to pandemic-related restrictions) but will test it out as soon I get physical access.

Answer (score 0):

When you add multiple public keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, any one having any private key for `remote-user` can login with `remote-user`.

Best and secure way to allow only particular user is to have separate account for individual user and its individual public key should be in `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Here Common account `Remote-User` should not be used. You can restrict users to allow via only ssh key in openssh. Thus separate user will have separate account only it will be able to login in its account.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH key identifies the user uniquely.  It can be re-used, but anyone that has the private key has full access to that identity.

Trying to add additional restrictions will be problematic.  The SSH key gives guarantee that the owner of the key has access to the key (i.e. as long as the owner maintains key privacy, the use of their key guarantees their identity).

Any other form of identifying the user, such as the source machine/IP-address for the connection, is not going to have the same level of guarantee.  In other words, those forms have a very real potential to be spoofed/tricked.

So here's the recommended solution:

- Run `ssh-keygen` for each of the users to give them a new, unique SSH key
- Replace the old key and dispose of it
- Add the public key of just the right user to the `authorized_keys` file
- Maintain key security; the key is the user's identity; allowing a second user access to the key gives them the ability to assume that identity at-will
- Don't try to work-around the problem with additional SSH settings as it is unlikely to be effective

Hope this helps!